# Can I customize the contact relationship tab to show custom fields?

Tags: custom-fields, relationships

I have a relationship type with some custom fields.  Is there any way to customize the relationship tab under a contact, to display those custom fields?  Instead of the default Start/End/City/State/Email/Phone?  I have looked at the templates used, and ultimately the data to populate the oTable seems to come from an ajax call to civicrm/ajax/contactrelationships

I'm pretty sure I'm at a dead end, but figured I'd ask here before giving up.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the Extension suggested below by Davejenx?

Comment: No, I was scared off by its being out of date, and this wasn't important enough to pursue down that probably dead-end.  I can't even find that extension now in the Extensions listing...

Comment: maybe it was this one? https://civicrm.org/extensions/custom-contact-relationships-tab/version-12

Comment: but not suggesting you try it, just trying to keep a record

Answer (score 2):

Which CiviCRM version are you using? If 4.4, then it looks as though this extension may do what you want:

[Custom Contact Relationships Tab](https://civicrm.org/extensions/custom-contact-relationships-tab)

If you're using a more recent CiviCRM version, it may be worth contacting the maintainer of that extension to see whether they are working on support for more recent versions.

There was some discussion of this feature on the old Civi forum in 2013:
[Changing relationship fields on the relationship tab](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=28985.0). But please continue the discussion here rather than there. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do this in 4.6 - if I understand what you mean correctly.  I added a custom set to a particular relationship type, and those custom fields show up when you click 'View' on one of the relationship items.

Comment: Thanks.  I do see the custom field when I click "View" on a specific relationship, but I wanted to change the default fields shown when you first click to the Relationship tab for a given contact.  Among other fields, it shows city, state, and phone...which I  don't need and hoped to replace with more useful fields.  I never found a way.