# Relationship -- change list's columns

Tags: relationships

I'd like to add some columns (eg. details of the address) and remove some columns (eg. State/Prov) to the table shown on a Contact's page, under the Relationships tab (there are tow of this table: one with the Current Relationships and an other with the Inactive Relationships).

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Pls see if https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/can-i-customize-the-contact-relationship-tab-to-show-custom-fields answers your question

Comment: or at least see if it replicates what you are asking. if it does, then this Q should be marked as a duplicate

Comment: Sorry, no, https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/can-i-customize-the-contact-relationship-tab-to-show-custom-fields doesn't give me answer. I forgot to mention, that my CiviCRM version is 5.10.3.

Comment: any update on this?
I also need to add / remove columns under the "current relationships".
I'm curring CiviCRM 5.13.4 Thanks Aris