# How to modify Relationships column display?

Tags: relationships, display

This is a new launch for an old question, see [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28602/relationship-change-lists-columns) and [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3522/can-i-customize-the-contact-relationship-tab-to-show-custom-fields).

We want to modify the columns that are shown in the relationships result display and especially replace city and state/county rows by job title.

Is this something we can now set in admin or do we need to create custom templates? We identified /CRM/Contact/Page/View/RelationshipSelector.tpl for example and are still looking for the body template.

Should we follow on this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Coleman's searchkit & formbuilder video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnL7-GRJ_2k) to see how to create a relationships display.

Comment: this is more than a good answer. searchkit and formbuilder open new horizons. Thanks Aidan :-)