# Add a custom field as a column in relationship tab

Tags: custom-fields, database, relationships, column

I added a column in relationship tab, to do that I edited the civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Relationship.php

I already added columns with fields existing in the base of civicrm but now I'm trying to add a custom field of a custom group as a column.

In the function makeURLClause() I don't know what to add in the select so it can select my custom field.

the name of the custom group is civicrm_value_r_le_11
the name of the custom value is fonction_dans_l_entreprise_83
I tried `civicrm_civicrm_value_r_le_11.custom_83 as custom_83,` but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to be modifying core files to do that.  See [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/39625/225) for a different approach.

Comment: I tried using searchkit but I don't think it is the right tool to do what I want. .Again, I already added field that already existed in CiviCRM to that tab but when I try with a custom field, it doesn't work