# Changing information under current relationships tab

Tags: relationships, column

I want to change the columns in the relationships tab within each organisation, such as adding each person's job title and removing Start, End and State/Prov. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate of other question such as

- [How to modify Relationships column display?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39625/how-to-modify-relationships-column-display)

which recommends using SearchKit to replace the Relationship Tab

Answer (score 0):

In a recent Civi update the relationship tab was replaced with SearchKit, which makes editing the display a lot easier (though it briefly also caused our relationships tab not to work). The answer then I found in this ticket: [Relationships not being displayed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45996/relationships-not-being-displayed/45997#45997)

From there, you can edit the searchkit table and form, but what was a lot easier for me was to edit the json before importing to add and remove the columns I wanted.