# Relationships not being displayed

Tags: relationships

I deleted my previous post because I am now seeing different behaviour. When looking at a contact record I selection relationships and see this:

[image]

I know this contact has multiple relationships but they just don't show here. I added a new relationship , the database tables were updated (I checked) but the relationship doesn't show.

Same for notes as well. I can see no errors being generated at all but it looks , to me with my naive view at the moment, that possibly permissions are not matching?

Any clues

I am running Joomla 4.4.1 , PHP 8.1 and CiviCRM 5.67.2

Edit

I started to look in FormBuilder and have noticed this

[image]

See next to the Form Settings all I am getting is a spinning wheel. If I try to create a new form that give me the option to Find Contacts. Is this showing that maybe this report is corrupt in some way?

I have another test instance and went to look in there and see this:

[image]

You can clearly see where it shows "Contacts Summary Relationships Active" in the spot where I have the "spinning wheel". What is causing that?

Comment: If you look in the browser console does it have any errors.

Comment: @Demerit , none that are obvious

Comment: Are you logged in as user 1 or administrator user?

Comment: Super user Pradeep

Comment: You can rule out permissions errors, because the problem is that the display is not rendering. It looks to me like the search displays might be completely missing, based on your second screenshot. Can you open SearchKit and click on "Packaged Searches" - look for a search named "Contact Summary Relationships" with 2 displays. Is it there?

Comment: Thanks Coleman , it's not there. When I look in my other site it is there. How do I restore that report back?

Comment: I had the same problem when upgrading to 5.67.x (can't remember which one exactly). I managed to fix it by upgrading again to the next version (it wasn't noticed straight away). Seems like this may be a bug? I also noticed that the display styling had been modified in the updated version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the relationship SK from the searchkit UI

```
    [
  [
    "SavedSearch",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "Contact_Summary_Relationships",
          "label": "Contact Summary Relationships",
          "api_entity": "RelationshipCache",
          "api_params": {
            "version": 4,
            "select": [
              "near_relation:label",
              "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.display_name",
              "start_date",
              "end_date",
              "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.address_primary.city",
              "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.address_primary.state_province_id:label",
              "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.email_primary.email",
              "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.phone_primary.phone",
              "permission_near_to_far:label",
              "permission_far_to_near:label",
              "is_active"
            ],
            "orderBy": [],
            "where": [],
            "groupBy": [],
            "join": [
              [
                "Contact AS RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01",
                "LEFT",
                [
                  "far_contact_id",
                  "=",
                  "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.id"
                ]
              ],
              [
                "Case AS RelationshipCache_Case_case_id_01",
                "LEFT",
                [
                  "case_id",
                  "=",
                  "RelationshipCache_Case_case_id_01.id"
                ]
              ]
            ],
            "having": []
          }
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    "SearchDisplay",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "Contact_Summary_Relationships_Active",
          "label": "Contact Summary Relationships Active",
          "saved_search_id.name": "Contact_Summary_Relationships",
          "type": "table",
          "settings": {
            "description": null,
            "sort": [],
            "limit": 50,
            "pager": {
              "hide_single": true,
              "expose_limit": true
            },
            "placeholder": 5,
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "near_relation:label",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "Relationship",
                "sortable": true,
                "icons": [
                  {
                    "field": "permission_far_to_near:icon",
                    "side": "left"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.display_name",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "With",
                "sortable": true,
                "icons": [
                  {
                    "field": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.contact_sub_type:icon",
                    "side": "left"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.contact_type:icon",
                    "side": "left"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "permission_near_to_far:icon",
                    "side": "right"
                  }
                ],
                "link": {
                  "path": "",
                  "entity": "Contact",
                  "action": "view",
                  "join": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01",
                  "target": "_blank"
                },
                "title": "View Related Contact"
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "start_date",
                "dataType": "Date",
                "label": "Dates",
                "sortable": true,
                "rewrite": "[start_date] - [end_date]"
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.address_primary.city",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "City",
                "sortable": true
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.address_primary.state_province_id:label",
                "dataType": "Integer",
                "label": "State/Prov",
                "sortable": true
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.email_primary.email",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "Email",
                "sortable": true,
                "icons": [
                  {
                    "icon": "fa-ban",
                    "side": "left",
                    "if": [
                      "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.do_not_email",
                      "=",
                      true
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.phone_primary.phone",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "Phone",
                "sortable": true,
                "icons": [
                  {
                    "icon": "fa-ban",
                    "side": "left",
                    "if": [
                      "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.do_not_phone",
                      "=",
                      true
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "text": "",
                "style": "default",
                "size": "btn-xs",
                "icon": "fa-bars",
                "links": [
                  {
                    "entity": "Relationship",
                    "action": "view",
                    "join": "",
                    "target": "crm-popup",
                    "icon": "fa-external-link",
                    "text": "View Relationship",
                    "style": "default",
                    "path": "",
                    "task": "",
                    "condition": []
                  },
                  {
                    "entity": "Relationship",
                    "action": "update",
                    "join": "",
                    "target": "crm-popup",
                    "icon": "fa-pencil",
                    "text": "Update Relationship",
                    "style": "default",
                    "path": "",
                    "task": "",
                    "condition": []
                  },
                  {
                    "task": "disable",
                    "entity": "Relationship",
                    "join": "",
                    "target": "crm-popup",
                    "icon": "fa-toggle-off",
                    "text": "Disable Relationship",
                    "style": "default",
                    "path": "",
                    "action": "",
                    "condition": [
                      "is_active",
                      "=",
                      true
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "entity": "Relationship",
                    "action": "delete",
                    "join": "",
                    "target": "crm-popup",
                    "icon": "fa-trash",
                    "text": "Delete Relationship",
                    "style": "danger",
                    "path": "",
                    "task": "",
                    "condition": []
                  },
                  {
                    "entity": "Case",
                    "action": "view",
                    "join": "RelationshipCache_Case_case_id_01",
                    "target": "",
                    "icon": "fa-folder-open",
                    "text": "Manage Case",
                    "style": "default",
                    "condition": []
                  }
                ],
                "type": "menu",
                "alignment": "text-right"
              }
            ],
            "actions": false,
            "classes": [
              "table",
              "table-striped"
            ],
            "toolbar": [
              {
                "action": "add",
                "entity": "Relationship",
                "text": "Add Relationship",
                "icon": "fa-plus",
                "style": "primary",
                "target": "crm-popup",
                "join": "",
                "path": "",
                "task": "",
                "condition": []
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Contact_Summary_Relationships_Inactive",
          "label": "Contact Summary Relationships Inactive",
          "saved_search_id.name": "Contact_Summary_Relationships",
          "type": "table",
          "settings": {
            "description": "These relationships are Disabled OR have a past End Date.",
            "sort": [],
            "limit": 50,
            "pager": {
              "hide_single": true,
              "expose_limit": true
            },
            "placeholder": 5,
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "near_relation:label",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "Relationship",
                "sortable": true,
                "icons": [
                  {
                    "field": "permission_far_to_near:icon",
                    "side": "left"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.display_name",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "With",
                "sortable": true,
                "icons": [
                  {
                    "field": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.contact_sub_type:icon",
                    "side": "left"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.contact_type:icon",
                    "side": "left"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "permission_near_to_far:icon",
                    "side": "right"
                  }
                ],
                "link": {
                  "path": "",
                  "entity": "Contact",
                  "action": "view",
                  "join": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01",
                  "target": "_blank"
                },
                "title": "View Related Contact"
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "start_date",
                "dataType": "Date",
                "label": "Dates",
                "sortable": true,
                "rewrite": "[start_date] - [end_date]"
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.address_primary.city",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "City",
                "sortable": true
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.address_primary.state_province_id:label",
                "dataType": "Integer",
                "label": "State/Prov",
                "sortable": true
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.email_primary.email",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "Email",
                "sortable": true,
                "icons": [
                  {
                    "icon": "fa-ban",
                    "side": "left",
                    "if": [
                      "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.do_not_email",
                      "=",
                      true
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.phone_primary.phone",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "Phone",
                "sortable": true,
                "icons": [
                  {
                    "icon": "fa-ban",
                    "side": "left",
                    "if": [
                      "RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01.do_not_phone",
                      "=",
                      true
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "text": "",
                "style": "default",
                "size": "btn-xs",
                "icon": "fa-bars",
                "links": [
                  {
                    "entity": "Relationship",
                    "action": "view",
                    "join": "",
                    "target": "crm-popup",
                    "icon": "fa-external-link",
                    "text": "View Relationship",
                    "style": "default",
                    "path": "",
                    "task": "",
                    "condition": []
                  },
                  {
                    "entity": "Relationship",
                    "action": "update",
                    "join": "",
                    "target": "crm-popup",
                    "icon": "fa-pencil",
                    "text": "Update Relationship",
                    "style": "default",
                    "path": "",
                    "task": "",
                    "condition": []
                  },
                  {
                    "task": "enable",
                    "entity": "Relationship",
                    "join": "",
                    "target": "crm-popup",
                    "icon": "fa-toggle-on",
                    "text": "Enable Relationship",
                    "style": "default",
                    "path": "",
                    "action": "",
                    "condition": [
                      "is_active",
                      "=",
                      false
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "entity": "Relationship",
                    "action": "delete",
                    "join": "",
                    "target": "crm-popup",
                    "icon": "fa-trash",
                    "text": "Delete Relationship",
                    "style": "danger",
                    "path": "",
                    "task": "",
                    "condition": []
                  }
                ],
                "type": "menu",
                "alignment": "text-right"
              }
            ],
            "actions": false,
            "classes": [
              "table",
              "table-striped",
              "disabled"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "saved_search_id",
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    "Afform",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "type": "search",
          "title": "Relationships",
          "permission": [
            "access CiviCRM"
          ],
          "placement": [
            "contact_summary_tab"
          ],
          "icon": "fa-handshake-o",
          "summary_weight": 80,
          "permission_operator": "AND",
          "layout": "<div af-fieldset=\"\">\n  <div class=\"alert alert-warning\">\n    <strong>{{:: ts('Permissioned Relationships:') }}</strong>\n    <i class=\"crm-i fa-eye\"></i> {{:: ts('This contact can be viewed by the other.') }}\n    <i class=\"crm-i fa-pencil-square\"></i> {{:: ts('This contact can be viewed and edited by the other.') }}\n  </div>\n  <crm-search-display-table search-name=\"Contact_Summary_Relationships\" display-name=\"Contact_Summary_Relationships_Active\" filters=\"{near_contact_id: options.contact_id, is_current: true}\"></crm-search-display-table>\n  <crm-search-display-table search-name=\"Contact_Summary_Relationships\" display-name=\"Contact_Summary_Relationships_Inactive\" filters=\"{near_contact_id: options.contact_id, is_current: false}\"></crm-search-display-table>\n</div>\n",
          "name": "afsearchTabRel",
          "modified_date": "2023-11-30 15:10:47",
          "requires": null,
          "entity_type": null,
          "join_entity": null,
          "description": null,
          "summary_contact_type": null,
          "server_route": null,
          "is_public": false,
          "redirect": null,
          "submit_enabled": true,
          "submit_limit": null,
          "create_submission": null,
          "navigation": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks Coleman , that has worked!