# view contact no relationship tab and note tab?

Tags: drupal

in view contact page, i can not see relationship tab and note tab in my project, i try to find reason, i clicked Display Preferences-> view contact setting, but only relationship tab and note tab no show on my view contact page, i dont know how to fix this bug.

civicrm 5.68 php 8.1

[image]

Comment: Do you have the contact layout editor extension enabled?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and resolved it by importing the SearchKit/Form. The info came from this answer: [Relationships not being displayed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45996/relationships-not-being-displayed/45997#45997)

Comment: i don't know import , i have searchkit plugin, but i clicked searchkit (civicrm/admin/search), is error page, 

now i hardcode relationship button and hardcode herf link (civicrm/contact/view/rel?reset=1&cid=11), but is no any data and table, i dont know how to fix

Comment: The import button is on the SearchKit page - the one you're getting an error for - so it sounds like you have bigger problems. What is the error? Your hardcoded link goes to the old relationship table that I guess doesn't work anymore. You need to figure out the searchkit problems first I think.

Comment: when i enter searchkit page, have message "There was a problem getting update information. Try again later.",
when i install civicrm, have some default plugin in this path (web/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/civicrm_admin_ui/ext/),
in this path all plug in is version 5.57.alpha1, I think it has something to do with version, my seting drupal 10, civicrm 5.68, but my plugin have many alpha1, i dont know how to fix