# Relationships and Notes tabs are missing when viewing a Contact

Tags: wordpress, relationships, notes

I recently upgraded to Civi 5.70.2 from 5.50.1. PHP 8.2. Wordpress. I thought I finally had everything working but today I see the Relationships and Notes tabs are missing when viewing a Contact, similar to:
[Relationships not being displayed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45996/relationships-not-being-displayed) and
[view contact no relationship tab and note tab?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/46314/view-contact-no-relationship-tab-and-note-tab)
I have the SearchKit installed. Oddly, it showed up on the Search Menu twice, but I was able to fix that with the Navigation Menu.  I have the Packaged Searches for Relationships and Notes:

[image]

I have tried running those searches, to no avail. Here's what a sample Contact looks like:
[image]

Please advise...thanks!

Comment: Are you using contact layour editor?

Comment: have you double checked that the Display settings are set to show them, at eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

Comment: Yes, regarding the Display Preferences, I tried unchecking them and saving, then rechecking them and saving...no joy...
Regarding the contact layout editor, I don't know what that is, so no.  The notes and relationships were working fine before the upgrade.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but this got added to the ConfigAndLog during the upgrade: 2024-03-18 15:52:31-0500  [info] Running task: Add "civicrm_note" to "note_used_for" option group

Comment: I tried adding the Contact Layout Editor Extension, but I can't see Notes and Relationships there either.  Please help!

Comment: are you still able to create Relationships?

Comment: The relationship tables and the notes tables are still there and seem fine, when viewed with phpMyAdmin.  The user interface is gone, so it would be hard to create a new one, but I'm sure you could do it with SQL.  I can use the Packaged Searches for Relationships and Notes to produce reports of them.  The only components being used are CiviMail and CiviReport, but I've tried adding all the components and I've tried removing and readding all the tabs in Display Preferences.

Comment: It seems like I need to give up on this version, and try either an newer version or older version.  I can still restore the 5.50.1 version, but I need to do that either today or tomorrow.  How did this bug get introduced?  What's my best bet for a working version?

Comment: I was able to import and run the Relationship search, as suggested here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45996/relationships-not-being-displayed  It didn't restore the Tab for Relationships on the View Contact screen.

Comment: I tried upgrading to 5.71.1, but it the Notes tab and Relationship Tabs still don't show up.  Weirdly, there's one new greyed out Tab:  "Official Info". I'm so frustrated...

Answer (score 2):

Relationships and Notes tab are using FormBuilder in the most recent versions.  My guess is that by updating from a version that old, it didn't enable them for whatever reason.  Try going to **Administer menu » System Settings » Extensions** and enable "Form Core" and "SearchKit".

Comment: Also - I recommend *not* installing Contact Layout Editor when you have an issue like this.  Pradeep's question was to determine whether it might be at fault, but it adds a complicating factor

Comment: Thanks Jon...I'm sure you're right.  Sadly, too late tho, since I gave up and went back to 5.50.1 while I still could.  Today, I upgraded to 5.58.1 and that seems to be working.  QUESTION:  Is "Form Core" the same as "Afform: Core Runtime"?

Comment: Today, I upgraded to 5.65.2 and everything seems to be working. So, I guess the lesson is, don't wait too long between upgrades...do one every time there's a Security Release.

Answer (score 1):

Since the one big upgrade didn't work, I had to do two smaller upgrades.  That worked, so I guess the lesson is, don't wait too long between upgrades...do one every time there's a Security Release

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
cv ev 'CRM_Contact_BAO_RelationshipCache::rebuild();'
```

for the Relationships issue.

If you run into `PHP Deprecation` errors, then trying downgrading your PHP version to 8.0.

Comment: Tabs still aren't there. We ran the command and no output was displayed except for multiple PHP errors and notices:
… /home/wiuta/www/www/vendor/bin/cv ev 'CRM_Contact_BAO_RelationshipCache::rebuild();'
[PHP Deprecation] Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$loadFilter is deprecated at /home/wiuta/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php:182
[PHP Deprecation] Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$loadPlugin is deprecated at...