# SearchKit not working - Entity SearchSegment not loaded

Tags: relationships, searchkit, notes

As described in [other questions](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45996/relationships-not-being-displayed/45997#45997), the tabs "notes" and "relationships" have disappeared from my contact summary page after they have been [updated to be based on SearchKit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27610). However I seem to have a more fundamental problem with SearchKit itself (so I cannot apply the usual fix to the problem): when I navigate to Search > SearchKit, the only thing I get is an error message:

`CRM_Core_Exception: Entity not loaded: SearchSegment in /somepath/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Service/Spec/SpecGatherer.php on line 91`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

System:

- CiviCRM 5.69.3
- Wordpress 6.4.2
- PHP 8.1
- Ubuntu 22.04.3

Comment: Sounds like this may be the root cause of your tabs not working. Can you check your db for the presence of the `civicrm_search_segment` table?

Comment: Thanks @Coleman, the table `civicrm_search_segment` is actually missing. Running the extension db updates via the admin site or by using `cv ext:db-upgrade-db` did not bring it back though. Is there any other way? Or do I have to recreate the table manually using the table definition in `search_kit/xml/schema/CRM/Search/SearchSegment.xml`?

Comment: I recommend you force the searchKit upgrader to re-run by doing: `UPDATE civicrm_extension SET schema_version = 1006 WHERE name = 'SearchKit';`

Then run `cv ext:upgrade-db`.

Comment: Thanks again, but no luck so far. The sql did not change any data until I added a blank between "Search" and "Kit". But even after that the `cv ext:upgrade-db`did not recreate the table `civicrm_search_segment`.

Comment: Ok, after trying a few more things unsuccessfully I solved the problem with brute force: I basically deleted everyting in the folder `wp-content/plugins/civicrm` and reinstalled the civicrm files from scratch. However I kept the database and the folder `wp-content/uploads/civicrm` unchanged. 
After logging into CiviCRM and updating the database everything seems to be running well, including the relationship and notes tabs.

Comment: Glad that worked