# Saved rules not showing

Tags: civirules, issues, bug-reporting

I have activated the CiviRules extension and created a workflow. It says it saved however the screen is empty when I go to Manage CiviRules. No filters selected it's just a general search. I checked both enabled and disabled but the list is blank. Does anyone know how this might be able to be fixed?

[image]

UPDATE: I did confirm the rules are showing in the database.

[image]

UPDATE 2: There are javascript errors on the page but they do not seem relevant?

[image]

Comment: Does the `civirule_rule` table have any entries?  (ie is the problem that it didn't save, or won't display)

Comment: @Aidan I have added a screenshot showing the data is in the database

Comment: Is there a javascript error in the browser console?

Comment: @Demerit I updated with a screenshot with the only 2 errors I see but I don't think they would matter in this case. please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Right that doesn't seem important. How about if you go into searchkit and on the packaged searches tab, and look at the searchkit for Civirules - does it maybe look like it's been corrupted or someone's edited it?

Comment: @Demerit we did have to do one search kit edit because there was a bug with my install (Drupal 10, CiviCRM 5.69) where relationships were not showing in profiles once saved (same issue as here actually). We did an update based on this fix https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45996/relationships-not-being-displayed

Comment: Ok then you could try a similar thing and import from https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/blob/master/managed/searchkit.mgd.php into the civirules packaged search just to make sure you have the right search definition.

Answer (score 2):

Ug stupid me didn't try the classic 'turn it off and on again approach'. I tried your searchkit idea @Demerit but that didn't work. So I instead disabled, uninstalled, and reinstalled, and now showing saved rules.

Thank you everyone for your support!!